# Getting the most played track out of the iPod library (MPMediaQuery)

Tags: iphone, ipod, mpmediaquery

I need to get out the 25 most Played Songs out from my iPod Library with my iPhone app. i am using a MPMediaQuery.

One solutions would be to loop through all tracks and them comparing by MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount. But i think thats a bit unefficient. Is there a way to directly get the Most Played items playlist?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for **MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount** not MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount. MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount is the track number of the song as it appears in its album.

**MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount** unfortunately **cannot be used for making queries** with MPMediaQuery since it is a user-defined property.

Your best option is to store all the play counts in a database like Core Data when your app is opened for the first time and update it by registering for notifications when the user's library changes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use NSSortDescriptor to sort the most played songs

`MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedSongsArray = [[everything items] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];`